# Does Nickell bias matter in forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, econometrics, panel-data, bias

The context is longitudinal data, with $i$ indexing individuals and $t$ indexing time.  The goal is predicting $y_{it}$ as a function of lags of $y$ as well as $\mathbf{X}$, which might include lags.  If you include fixed effects, the model is

$$
y_{it} = \alpha_i + \mathbf{Y}_{it}^L\Gamma + \mathbf{X}_{it}\beta +\epsilon_{it}
$$

where $\mathbf{Y}^L$ are all of the lags of $y$ that you're using.

It was [established by Nickell](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1911408?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) that OLS coefficient estimates of this dynamic fixed effects model are inconsistent, because the within or differencing transformation used to remove the fixed effects will create a mechanical correlation between the error term and the $\mathbf{X}$'s.  A random effects model would have the same problem.

But what if I don't care about inference, and only want to do forecasting?  Should I expect that $\hat{y}_{t+1}$ should be biased as well, if I only use actual observations of $\mathbf{X}$, and don't do any scenario analysis?

I'm not sure how to think about this.

Comment: The inconsistency will be inherited by the predictions. However, FE estimator is inconsistent for large N and small T panels, but will get much better as you get more T.